# Executing a jar inside shell script

Tags: executable-jar

i found many related questions here. I have a simple java program . it does not contain a main function. It has a function which takes a string and returns the same . I have made it into a jar file. My question is can i call/ execute this jar file from a shell script. i tested the file in windows using eclipse by creating a new class which has a main function and creating an object of the other class and calling the function. Any help would be appreciated. Pardon me if this is a trivial task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute the jar as an application without there being a `main()` routine somewhere; you'll have to write one and either add it to the jar (this would be easiest!) or create a second jar, or just leave it loose. In any case, one way or another you'll need to execute the class that contains the `main()` method.

[Here](http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html) are some simple instructions for creating an executable jar file, given that you've got that `main()`-containing class. Once you have the jar, you can run it using `java -jar thejar.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That helped. Another problem is how do i call a particular function inside a class ?

Comment: If it's a static function, then just `ClassName.functionName();`. If it's not, then you have to create an instance of the class -- `new ClassName().functionName();` .

Comment: you mean 'new Classname().functionName()' as the command line argument in  "java -cp jarfile argument" ?

Comment: No, I mean that's the code in the body of `main()`. Java is a compiled language -- you can't pass snippets or lines of code around like scripts.

Comment: sorry for not doing that ? could you show me how to do the same ? I have clicked on the 'was this post useful to you link' as 'yes' . is that what you mean ?